# SQL Search Query with Dynamic search condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I  have an old dynamic SQL query as below where the conditions in the where clause is appended dynamically based on the search text.

> **Example 1** : Search string **'AMX AC-DIN-CS3 Bracket'**

```
SELECT * FROM Tx_Product
Where Fk_CompanyId=1   
and  (ModelNumber like '%AMX%' or Manufacturer like '%AMX%' or Category like '%AMX%' or [Description] like '%AMX%')
and  (ModelNumber like '%AC-DIN-CS3%' or Manufacturer like '%AC-DIN-CS3%' or Category like '%AC-DIN-CS3%' or [Description] like '%AC-DIN-CS3%')
and  (ModelNumber like '%Bracket%' or Manufacturer like '%Bracket%' or Category like '%Bracket%' or [Description] like '%Bracket%')
```

Here there are 3 And Clauses as there are 3 parts in the search string (separated by space(AMX,AC-DIN-CSS3 and Bracket).

> **Example 2** : Search string **'AMX AC-DIN-CS3'**

```
SELECT * FROM Tx_Product
Where Fk_CompanyId=1   
and  (ModelNumber like '%AMX%' or Manufacturer like '%AMX%' or Category like '%AMX%' or [Description] like '%AMX%')
and  (ModelNumber like '%AC-DIN-CS3%' or Manufacturer like '%AC-DIN-CS3%' or Category like '%AC-DIN-CS3%' or [Description] like '%AC-DIN-CS3%')
```

Here there are 2 And Clauses as there are 2 parts in the search string (AMX, AC-DIN-CS3).

I want to get rid of the **Dynamic sql** and create a single query that will get me the same result as above based on the search string but i am getting  different result.

> Equivalent of **Example 1** But With extra results

```
DECLARE @SearchString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'AMX AC-DIN-CS3 Bracket'

SELECT DISTINCT Prod.* FROM Tx_Product Prod
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT part FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@SearchString,'')) AS SearchParts
Where  Fk_CompanyId = 1
AND (ModelNumber LIKE SearchParts.part OR Prod.Manufacturer LIKE SearchParts.part 
OR Prod.Category LIKE SearchParts.part OR Prod.[Description] LIKE SearchParts.part)
```

Here i get the extra records like ( all the Products with manufacturer **'AMX'** and all the products with ModelNumber **'AC-DIN-CS3'**).

**Question:** I want help in building the single query (Equv. of Example 1, that will give me the same result as of Example 1) based on the search string.
 So, this new Equiv query with tweaks will satisfy for both the example.

I have update the schema in [SQL Fidddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e0f0/14/0)  As well.

Thanks in Advance for help.

---

**Note:** `[dbo].[SplitString]` returns the distint parts of the string as a table.
Here for `'AMX-AC-DIN-CS3'` it will return

```
'AMX'
'AC-DIN-CS3'
```

Comment: Does your table `Tx_Product` have a field with unique `ID`?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov yes i have a Primary key Pk_ProductID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use CTEs to make the query text more readable.

I assume that the table `Tx_Product` has a primary key `ID`.

At first we convert `@SearchString` to a table. Then count number of rows in it to get the total number of keywords.

You want to find those products that have all the given keywords.

For each keyword we use `CROSS APPLY` to get a list of product IDs that have this keyword. Then we group by ID to count the number of matches and keep only those IDs that have the number of matches the same as total number of keywords.

Finally, we fetch all product details from the table using the found IDs.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3af58/5/0) based on yours.

```
WITH
CTE_Parts
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT '%' + part + '%' AS Part
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@SearchString,'')
)
,CTE_PartCount
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS PartCount
    FROM CTE_Parts
)
,CTE_ProductIDs
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
    FROM
        CTE_Parts
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT ID
            FROM Tx_Product
            WHERE
                Fk_CompanyId = 1
                AND (ModelNumber LIKE CTE_Parts.Part
                    OR Manufacturer LIKE CTE_Parts.Part
                    OR Category LIKE CTE_Parts.Part
                    OR [Description] LIKE CTE_Parts.Part)
        ) AS CA
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT PartCount FROM CTE_PartCount)
)
SELECT
    Tx_Product.*
FROM
    CTE_ProductIDs
    INNER JOIN Tx_Product ON Tx_Product.ID = CTE_ProductIDs.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the partial matches.

Try the query below.

The match for each keyword get its number and if product max number is equal to total count of keywords, then the match is full and product should be selected

```
select * from 
(
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Prod.* 
    ,row_number() over 
        (partition by Pk_ProductID
        order by SearchParts.part) as num
FROM Tx_Product Prod
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT '%'+part+'%' as part FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@SearchString,'')) AS SearchParts
Where  Fk_CompanyId = 1
AND (ModelNumber LIKE SearchParts.part OR Prod.Manufacturer LIKE SearchParts.part 
OR Prod.Category LIKE SearchParts.part OR Prod.[Description] LIKE SearchParts.part)
) T
-- the number of last line for product
-- is equal to total count of keywords
where T.num = (SELECT count(DISTINCT part) FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@SearchString,''))
```

Comment: you are pretty close, i have 2  products (in the result set both having Manufacture as 'AMX', Model = 'AC-DIN-CS3' and Category= 'Bracket',   but  your answer  gets only 1 record.

Comment: Ahh got it, T.num > (SELECT count(DISTINCT part) FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@SearchString,''))  fixed the issue.

Comment: with the search string as 'AMX', i should get all the Products with Manufacturers as 'AMX' there are 8 results,  but with your query i am getting only 1 record.

Comment: @sudhAnsu63, it can help if you impove `partition by` part of `row_number`. and i can't test. can you create an sqlFiddle?

Comment: I have added the Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
select *
from Tx_Product prod
where prod.Fk_CompanyId=1
    and exists (
        select 1
        from (
            select up.Pk_ProductID, up.Fk_CompanyId, up.attribute, up.value
            from (select p.Pk_ProductID, p.Fk_CompanyId
                    , CONVERT(varchar(max),p.ModelNumber) ModelNumber
                    , CONVERT(varchar(max),p.Manufacturer) Manufacturer
                    , CONVERT(varchar(max),p.Category) Category
                    , CONVERT(varchar(max),p.[Description]) [Description]
                from Tx_Product p) p
            unpivot (value for attribute in (ModelNumber, Manufacturer, Category, [Description])) up
            ) p
            join [dbo].[SplitString] (@SearchString,'') s on p.value like '%'+s.part+'%'
            and p.Pk_ProductID=prod.Pk_ProductID        
        having COUNT(distinct s.part)=(select COUNT(1) from [dbo].[SplitString] (@SearchString,''))
            )
```

Comment: Its Not Working,  returning all the records . you can check in the Fiddle.

Comment: There was multiple match on one keyword, and no one on the other. I correct the solution.